# Teste unitário RxJS + NgRx subscription no Angular com Karma

Tags: angular

Estou com dificuldade de executar teste unitário para a seguinte função:

```
subscribeToUsuario(): void {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.store$.pipe(select(selectors.selectUsuario)).subscribe(state => {
        if (!state || !state.usuario) return;
        this.usuario = state.usuario;
      })
    );
  }
```

No istanbul sempre bate como *function/statement not covered*, qual seria a forma ideal de testar essa função?

Comment: Poderia postar também o conteúdo do teste unitário? O código postado é o que está sendo testado, correto?

Comment: o que seria esse subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você poderia fazer dessa maneira:

1- dentro da suíte de testes, você iria criar uma propriedade para o store que contem um spy para o pipe:

```
const storeMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['pipe']);
```

2- criar um mock que possua a mesma estrutura de retorno do seu seletor.

3- No providers dentro do seu configureTestingModule você iria associar seu spy com o modulo da biblioteca dessa maneira:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: Store, useValue: storeMock },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

4- Dentro do seu caso de teste você iria adcionar o spy dessa maneira:

```
storeMock.pipe.and.returnValue(of(selectUsuarioMock));
```